# Mysql query - find sum not in multiple range (Evergreen)

Tags: mysql, database

I need to fetch some data from mySql evergreen period (total - some prmo periods) ;

```
SELECT SUM(view) AS tUniquePageViews FROM store_report_per_day WHERE tpi = 'SE0541' AND YEAR(trxDate) = '2018'
```

> Total : 462

```
SELECT SUM(view) AS tUniquePageViews FROM store_report_per_day WHERE tpi = 'SE0541' AND trxDate >= '2017-03-03' AND trxDate <= '2017-09-12'
```

> 0

```
SELECT SUM(view) AS tUniquePageViews FROM store_report_per_day WHERE tpi = 'SE0541' AND trxDate >= '2018-09-11' AND trxDate <= '2019-01-03'
```

> 5

```
SELECT SUM(view) AS tUniquePageViews FROM store_report_per_day WHERE tpi = 'SE0541' AND trxDate >= '2018-07-01' AND trxDate <= '2018-09-04'
```

> 218

```
SELECT SUM(view) AS tUniquePageViews FROM store_report_per_day WHERE tpi = 'SE0541' AND trxDate >= '2018-08-01' AND trxDate <= '2018-08-18'
```

> 4

```
SELECT SUM(view) AS tUniquePageViews FROM store_report_per_day WHERE tpi = 'SE0541' AND trxDate >= '2018-07-01' AND trxDate <= '2018-07-31'
```

> 4

```
SELECT SUM(view) AS tUniquePageViews FROM store_report_per_day WHERE tpi = 'SE0541' AND trxDate >= '2018-06-15' AND trxDate <= '2018-06-30'
```

> 2

Now I need to fetch Total - (All periods) My query is

```
SELECT SUM(view) AS tUniquePageViews FROM store_report_per_day WHERE tpi = 'SE0541' AND  1 AND (trxDate < '2018-09-11' OR trxDate > '2018-10-25')  AND (trxDate < '2018-07-01' OR trxDate > '2018-09-04')  AND (trxDate < '2018-08-01' OR trxDate > '2018-08-18')  AND (trxDate < '2018-07-01' OR trxDate > '2018-07-31')  AND (trxDate < '2018-06-15' OR trxDate > '2018-06-30')
```

> My desired Output is
>
> 462-0-5-218-4-4-2 = 229  But i am getting 237

When I hit queries for 1 or 2 date range it show fine result but all together not.

What is the issue in my query.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just union all your queries together to get the final sum?

```
SELECT SUM(tUniquePageViews) FROM
(
  SELECT SUM(view) AS tUniquePageViews FROM store_report_per_day WHERE tpi = 'SE0541' AND YEAR(trxDate) = '2018' 
  union all
  SELECT SUM(view) AS tUniquePageViews FROM store_report_per_day WHERE tpi = 'SE0541' AND trxDate >= '2017-03-03' AND trxDate <= '2017-09-12' 
  union all
  SELECT SUM(view) AS tUniquePageViews FROM store_report_per_day WHERE tpi = 'SE0541' AND trxDate >= '2018-09-11' AND trxDate <= '2019-01-03' 
  union all
  SELECT SUM(view) AS tUniquePageViews FROM store_report_per_day WHERE tpi = 'SE0541' AND trxDate >= '2018-07-01' AND trxDate <= '2018-09-04' 
  union all
  SELECT SUM(view) AS tUniquePageViews FROM store_report_per_day WHERE tpi = 'SE0541' AND trxDate >= '2018-08-01' AND trxDate <= '2018-08-18'
  union all
  SELECT SUM(view) AS tUniquePageViews FROM store_report_per_day WHERE tpi = 'SE0541' AND trxDate >= '2018-07-01' AND trxDate <= '2018-07-31'
  union all
  SELECT SUM(view) AS tUniquePageViews FROM store_report_per_day WHERE tpi = 'SE0541' AND trxDate >= '2018-06-15' AND trxDate <= '2018-06-30' 
) a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using conditional aggregation

```
    SELECT 
    SUM(case when YEAR(trxDate) = '2018' then view end)- 
    SUM(case when trxDate >= '2017-03-03' AND trxDate <= '2017-09-12' then view end) - 
    SUM(case when trxDate >= '2018-09-11' AND trxDate <= '2019-01-03' then view end)-
    SUM(case when trxDate >= '2018-07-01' AND trxDate <= '2018-09-04' then view end)-
    SUM(case when trxDate >= '2018-08-01' AND trxDate <= '2018-08-18' then view end)-
    SUM(case when trxDate >= '2018-07-01' AND trxDate <= '2018-07-31' then view end)-
    SUM(case when trxDate >= '2018-06-15' AND trxDate <= '2018-06-30' then view end)
    AS tUniquePageViews 
    FROM store_report_per_day WHERE tpi = 'SE0541'
```